# For loops - Forms

Tags: python

I am learning python, coming from c++. From what I am reading, there only appears to be two forms of for loops in python. I can either iterate over a range, or through the elements of a collection. I suppose the former really is the latter...so maybe one form.

Is there any other form?

I am used to looping until a condition is false. There doesn't seem to be a way to evaluate a condition in a for loop in Python. Is that correct?

Since there is no (init;condition;post) , how would you do something like iterate over every other string in a collection of strings, in python?

C++ would look like:

```
string mystuff[] = {"poop", "dooky", "doodoo"};
for(size_t index = 0; index < 3; index += 2)
    cout << mystuff[index];
```

Comment: actually there is one form of for. iterating over an iterable. there are lots of iterable data structures (or, more c++esque, there are lots of data structures, implementing iterable interface) - typed arrays, lists, tuples, dicts, strings etc.

Comment: For this kind of iteration you would use range(<start>, <end>, <stepWidth>)... not sure if i got the order right here but you get the idea: range/xrange gives you basically the same functionality as a regular cpp for-loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A for loop is the same thing as a while loop, just in a slightly different syntax.  If you have a for loop that looks like

```
for(init; condition; post)
  //do something
```

that is equivalent to the while loop

```
init;
while(condition)
  //do something
  post;
```

because Python has while loops, if you wanted to iterate over every other string, you would change

```
string mystuff[] = {"poop", "dooky", "doodoo"};
for(size_t index = 0; index < 3; index += 2)
  cout << mystuff[index];
```

to

```
mystuff = [ "poop", "dooky", "doodoo" ]
index = 0
while index < 3:
  print(mystuff[index])
  index += 2
```

Answer (score 1):

(Most Common)Three kinds of loops :

1. `Count controlled` - You dont have this kind of loop in python
2. `Condition controlled` - while loop in python
3. `Collection controlled` - for loop in python

Answer (score 1):

> I am used to looping until a condition is false. There doesn't seem to
>   be a way to evaluate a condition in a for loop in Python. Is that
>   correct?

Correct. For loops don't evaluate conditions by themselfs, they iterate through an iterable. When you write `for i in something`, that `something` must be an [iterable](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterable). See the link for more details.
The important part is that a for loop goes through **all** the elements of the iterable. If you want to skip one or more elements, you have to implement a condition inside the loop (like `if i == certain_value: continue`) or build a second iterable where you exclude the elements that must be skipped and use the for loop on that.

> Since there is no (init;condition;post) , how would you do something
>   like iterate over every other string in a collection of strings, in
>   python?

There is an high chance that a collection of string is an iterable (depends of what object you use to collect the strings). If you need conditions on the index you can use [range()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) and use indexes, or [enumerate()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate). If fact there are several ways to obtain the same result, other answers already pointed out few of them.

Your c++ code:

```
string mystuff[] = {"poop", "dooky", "doodoo"};
for(size_t index = 0; index < 3; index += 2)
    cout << mystuff[index];
```

can be rendered for example using *range()*:

```
ll = ["poop", "dooky", "doodoo"]
for i in range(0, len(ll), 2):
    print(ll[i])
```

In this case `range(0, len(ll), 2)` is an iterable. In python2 would be a list: `[0, 2]`. In python3 is a range object, which if converted to a list would be again `[0, 2]`.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this (credit to @Teghan for pointing out [::2] version):

```
>     myStrs = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']
> 
>     for i in range(0, len(myStrs), 2):
>         print(myStrs[i])
> 
>     print([(myStrs[i]) for i in range(0, len(myStrs), 2)])
>     print([x+"a" for x in myStrs[::2]])
```

Output:

> ```
>  A
>  C 
>  E
>  ['A', 'C', 'E']
>  ['Aa', 'Ca', 'Ea']
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You might be searching for [while](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_while_loops.asp) loops

Answer (score 0):

You want a while loop:

```
i = 0
n = int
while i < n:

    # do something

    if some_possible_condition = True:

        i = i + 1
```

To your specific example:

> how would you do something like iterate over every other string in a collection of strings, in python?

You could use a for loop and check a condition:

```
strings = ['string1', 'string2', ... , 'stringN']

for i in range(len(strings)):
    if i % 2 == 0:

         # do things to strings[i]
```

But a more pythonic way would be to access only every other element in the list of strings using list indexing, and process each string:

```
for each_even_string in strings[::2]:

    # do things to each_even_string
```

Comment: Iterating through all of them and filtering out the unwanted ones seems less efficient than only iterating through the wanted ones.